# LinearLayout background not found

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-drawable, nine-patch

I know this background image exists and it's in the following *drawable* folders:

- res/drawable-mdpi/
- res/drawable-hdpi/
- res/drawable-xhdpi/
- res/drawable-xxhdpi/

The file is named `coming_up.9.png` as it's a nine patch and I know this works because I'm doing the same with a number of other images.

**Layout XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/coming_up">
```

**The Error**

```
Error:(213, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/coming_up').
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing with this issue for a while now and I decided today was the day to tackle it. Here's how I solved the problem:

**Steps I Took:**

1. Changed background to a different (working) image named `@drawable/checkbox_checked` to see what would happen - app ran fine with the new image
2. Searched for `checkbox_checked` in my resource folder `/res` to see where it existed
3. Found that `checkbox_checked.png` was only in the main `/drawable` folder
4. Copied `coming_up.9.png` to `/drawable` from `/drawable-mdpi` - still the same error
5. Renamed `coming_up.9.png` to `coming_up.png` - worked
6. Renamed `coming_up.png` back to `coming_up.9.png` - still worked
7. Removed `coming_up.9.png` from `/drawable` while leaving it in all of my other drawable folders - worked

Seemingly this is a bug with **Android Studio** that was somehow resolved at step #5. Regardless this issue is solved so I hope this saves someone the time it took me to figure it out.